# Manjaro and DualShock 3

Tags: controller, gamepad, playstation3, manjaro

I recently installed Manjaro in hope of getting a linux that would not be a ubuntu or debian derivat but convenient to use.

I'm using Manjaro 4.14.74-1 with cinnamon.

When I plug in my DualShock 3 controller (gamepad), most linux instantly recognize that and it's usable at the first try.

But **Manjaro will recognize it as an usb device** (listed as 'DualShock 3' in lsusb) but no evdev or sth like that is there to use it.

So it doesn't recognize it as a controller or maybe I don't have the needed kernel modules or something like that but i really don't know what to do.

How do I get my dualshock 3 to work?

thanks

EDIT:

Running `mhwd -lh -d --usb` has the following output:

```
10: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 3-1:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Sony Batoh Device / PlayStation 3 Controller"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x054c "Sony Corp."
  Device: usb 0x0268 "Batoh Device / PlayStation 3 Controller"
  Revision: "1.00"
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v054Cp0268d0100dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00in00"
  Attached to: #7 (Hub)
```

Comment: Can you check if you have the hid-sony kernel module?

Comment: yes i do. /lib/modules/4.14.77-1-MANJARO/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-sony.ko.xz

Comment: So it seems like if the ds3 controller is plugged in while i'm booting, the needed modules are loaded correctly and i'm able to use it. But if i plug in the controller after my system is booted then i have the problem as explained. And if i try to sudo modprobe hid-sony or hid_sony, then modprobe cannot find the module

Answer (score 2):

I think the Problem was, that "uname -r" didn't match with the directory name of the modules and the actual version of the kernel.
I could fix it with a symbolic link. I ran `sudo modprobe hid_sony`, and i got something like

> modprobe: FATAL: Module hid-sony not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.78-1-MANJARO

but the actual kernel version is 4.14.79-1-MANJARO and so is the name of the existing directory with all the modules. so i i ran

```
sudo ln -s /lib/modules/4.14.79-1-MANJARO/ /lib/modules/4.14.78-1-MANJARO 
sudo depmod -a`
```

and now it's working properly. This fix will probably last till the next time i upgrade the kernel but it's quick and easy and gets the job done.